# Unable to segue to VC without dismissing SearchController

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue, uisearchcontroller

I'm unable to transition to my View Controller without having dismissed my Search Controller. My search controller is embedded in my TableView Header.

Is there a way of transitioning without having dismissed my Search Controller first?

Here is some code:

```
class ViewProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, 
UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search City"
searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white      
self.myTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
// Get rid of searchController
searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
searchController.isActive = false
searchController.dismiss(animated: true) { /* */ }

// Deselect row
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

// Present your VC here
let mViewController = MController()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: 
mViewController)
present(navController,animated: true, completion: nil)

}

}
```

Comment: You can't present this view controller while your search controller is active. You should use the `push` instead of `present`. Also you must define a presentation context

Comment: Also do not declare as `let`, it's should be `var`

Comment: @Mannopson Why var? The searchController for example never changed to something else, so let is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs I agree. Do you know a way to transition to another view without having to dismiss my search controller?

Comment: What you could do is to save your search input somewhere and when you come back insert the search again.